# Spring-Boot on mac with Java 8, Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: macos, spring-boot, java-8, environment-variables, java-home

I created a sample spring-boot project on my mac.  But when I try to run maven commands on it (such as `mvn spring-boot:run`), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

followed of course by the obligatory stack trace.  I know from reading answers on many other similar (but not identical) questions, that this has something to do with compiling with a more recent version of Java, and then running with an earlier version of Java.  According to this chart:

```
J2SE 8 = 52
J2SE 7 = 51
J2SE 6.0 = 50
J2SE 5.0 = 49
JDK 1.4 = 48
JDK 1.3 = 47
JDK 1.2 = 46
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

I must have somehow compiled with Java 7, and then somehow run with Java 6.  But I don't understand how this can be so.  I'm pretty sure I'm using Java 8.  For one thing, when I enter `java -version` in the terminal, I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Also, my pom clearly specifies to use Java 8:

```
  <project>

    <!-- project info -->

    <name>springboot-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- dependencies -->

  </project>
```

All the answers I've read so far say to compile with Java 6, or to just use Java 8... but I am using Java 8!  Also, since the error I'm getting says "51.0" instead of "52.0", doesn't that mean I'm compiling with Java 7?  As far as I know, I am only using Java 8!

Most importantly, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lay in the fact that I did not have an explicit JAVA_HOME.

When typing `which java` into the terminal, I would get 
`/usr/bin/java`
which is merely a symbolic link pointing to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{jdk-version}/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

Under the JavaVirtualMachines directory, I had two folders:

- 1.6.0.jdk
- jdk1.8.0_25.jdk

So I did infact have a Java 6 installation after all!  Even though /usr/bin/java was pointing to the directory for Java 8, and the version in my terminal was Java 8, when I tried to run maven it was using the Java 6 installation!

To fix this I needed to set my JAVA_HOME environment variable and add it to my PATH.  Before I did this, when typing `echo $JAVA_HOME` into the terminal, I got back nothing.

I created a file named .bash_profile in my home directory (since I didn't already have one).  I then put the following in it:

```
  export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
  export MAVEN_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.3.9
  export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I restarted my terminal, navigated to my project, entered `mvn spring-boot:run`, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: if you add `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` to your `.profile`, then you will always have `JAVA_HOME` set to the current version. `/usr/libexec/java_home -h`shows some more info